# Perhaps run the command 'git lfs install' from the GIT project

Tags: git

I use `repo upload` command.
I configured git lfs on my repo but I still get error:
Perhaps run the command 'git lfs install' from the GIT project

if I use `git push` then it works.

What can be a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try again with a dummy repository, following the "[Git LFS Tutorial](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial)".

That tutorial does include the `git lfs install` step, which refers to [the installation page](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Installation).
It lists as requirements a Git more than 1.8.2. And some instructions per OS.

Comment: I forgot to write that I use repo upload @VonC

Comment: @Alex Try first without the "repo" wrapper.

Comment: Do you have any idea ? @VonC

Comment: @Alex Once the lfs install done (without repo), would the repo command still generate the error message?

Comment: What do you mean ? Can you give me more details ? @VonC

Comment: @Alex I don't have access to a similar environment, so I don't have more details to provide.